# Migrating an off-topic question to another forum?

Tags: discussion

While searching for a "recipe", I found [this link on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux) that contains useful (for me) information. It has been **closed as off-topic** and **locked** for some time. As it's considered off-topic here, I wondered if it could be migrated to another forum where it might be "on-topic". For example, [the Unix forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)? It's quite a useful Q&A IMHO, and may benefit from some more current answers.

Comment: Why should it be migrated? It is locked for historical reference. It has has 750K views. Probably a lot of incoming links. Migrating that will break lots of the internet. Did you check with the Unix.se folks if it is on-topic there and if they want this question?

Comment: @rene: `Why?`: "It's quite a useful Q&A IMHO, and may benefit from some more current answers." Re `break lots of the internet`: Can't the existing Q&A be edited to add/replace with a redirect or link to this Q on Unix.se? `Did I check?` No... I assumed they would since it is relevant in that forum. In my limited experience this is "how things are done" here at SE... do you have constructive suggestions?

Comment: I normally hop in their chat if I expect something to be of value for them. And no, there is no permanent redirect, the migration stub will only exist for 30 days and will then be deleted.

Comment: Oh well, that's too bad. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Here is a link to the rather complicated migration FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: SE sites are not forums.

Comment: @gre_gor I think they are, but they are strongly hardened against crap & chit-chat. The "SE is not a forum" is an useful ideology to explain this hardening on an amicable way. (Compare to: "Wikipedia is not a lexicon")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am 3K on the Unix SE and in my opinion, the question is on-topic there. It might be a dupe, but on-topic.

This question can't be migrated on the following reasons:

1. It is older than 2 months. Questions older than 2 months can't be migrated.<sup>1</sup>
2. It is already closed. Even if this question would be younger than 2 months, it still couldn't be migrated because migration can happen only as part of a closure vote.<sup>2</sup> To migrate it, it should be first reopened, and then again closed, but with the reason *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"*. (To reopen, first a mod should also unlock it.)
3. Unix SE is not a community migration path from the SO, what means that community votes can't migrate posts to it. Only the SU, Tex, Dba and Stats SE are community migration targets. Only mods can migrate posts to it, but doing this would be their responsibility from that point. And they need to withstand already many critics; they are held on a short leash by the SE; and they don't like to risk. Furthermore, there were cases in the past, that community migrations caused conflicts between the sites and/or the site mods, this is obviously not the interest of anybody.

However, the most fair and welcoming way to handle such posts would be to migrate them.

A closed question means a bad experience for the OP about 1 site.

Having a migrated question would be a good experience for the OP with 2 sites.

Why the SE doesn't do it - more exactly, why are the possibilities of a community migration so strongly hardened, with the obvious intent to make them nearly impossible?

Uhm.... that is a good question...

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>SE employee actually can do that, but it happens only in every leap century. ;-)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Mods can migrate questions without a community vote, but they do this only rarely, as detailed in (3) and in the comments.</sub>

Comment: yes... a good question. Appreciate the straightforward answer.

Comment: @rene Mods are for human exceptions, migrations are for off-topic, but elsewhere on-topic posts. If a rational, welcoming, non-destructive community migration voting system would exist, it should happen by community votes, similarly to the closures.

Comment: @rene I think the best would be if avid voters of the *target* sites could hunt for off-topic closed good questions on anywhere. It would be particularly useful for small betas: it could help a lot to build their initial content base, and to reach the maturation more quickly.

Comment: @rene I extended the post with a footer, to detail it. But somehow I have the feeling, that it won't be enough for a sign change...

Comment: @rene 1. I did not adviced to do that (it would be impossible because the question lock). 2. The close reason exists, I've just checked it. The correct formulation is: *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"*. 3. It might not exist on questions older than 2 months.